# How can i get pdf file from GET request, and get text from it?

Tags: node.js, pdf

I make GET request to https://easypay.ua/ua/contacts  from form check transaction on this site

```
request({method: 'GET', url:'https://api.easypay.ua/api/payment/getReceipt?receiptId=855277203&amount=1', headers: {'Accept': 'application/pdf'}}, (err, res, body) => { 
  console.log(body);
  console.log(res.statusCode);

})
```

In 'body' i get strings like this:

> %PDF-1.4
> %âãÏÓ
> 3 0 obj
> <</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 700/Height 281/Length 39901/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
> xœì]w@IŸM£A•n{¯¨`WÄÛœÏÞ»§¢g;»g;{ïHµ+ˆ 6Þ{ï„ž}ßî&¡x–;¥¿üþ€dvv3;ûÛ7ï½yó!%”PB  %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB    %”PB‰¯Ç¼yK6/6|å¡•#†¶c6tk”Pâè4ùäà–ðDÒùé<(‰‰ t?ru£9RQc`
> ÝR%” Ñ´Ïè•û–¸®=è›
> €‹Äð)à|®€[È):éÔ¿•Q³F
> Ýn%þ¿¡×k„ËÉ·    œÒ2AZŠ’CÿAZüƒnû¹}®“G7ièö+ñÿ †–Y?·¨Ü¡œ‘bŸã{ä¯ù>÷8¨â“Ò7ëÆ¹’çìüÄ»ëLú.”øÿÖdÌ_   2:–…Åy™"    —íí0Î£×oÊþu3~a!Ôöjð_ÞÅùà†w¨ÛÐ÷¢Äÿ;®¸\Nd1a"ÀßîpR"Ew®õpÞ…q?ÁÝ4;ò|m­µ\â…ï¹‚â’€ª:ª
> }GJü ¹ÛkŽT‹-9¶6 y"m…D"á¿8•¢OšjRpjé[Ù7ñú•áüËìt¢HRš:«•Rú*Q×`ö?›Ì#—’TÜëóÂD‰þ\ˆ%5X*)-» #æ]Ðã»çï—Éµâl_¯ŒŠUNÙj·dÌãq^,Ø[B¼™»í­•®3%êj6NWcøâØPà7u'®ìåïo¥éJ¦Æ¾}âyùè®ßçNçÐ±uSã¦zºzÍ´ÚŸ¶Ù+ðÑë2)™EþWŸü´÷¬êÉ25Ç,ÑûÀü~¥¾JÔ
> T»»=Ž&˜Wº¸S~ù\d»qgZº§Ü(äçœh¥ÕXK•Å¤ÓiDma5©vsýÆÃ—œˆOO­ ØþNTq(z
> ¡èÈñîäWNèÏiçz5Ì)ñCká°ì™T›-pEæÇ#œºÏ½G~/à3•EûW—AÈÀ ó¡gÉ…0£UofÇ˜ÈeË€7¤è~½u„ÒlS¢VÁÐêxA®Îâ¯Œé[x€ ƒø’usáÀ¶†êÿBYmwg‹z‹.:äGuç…®Ç^
> #¹pÁÂ

Which ends like:

> <</Type/Pages/Count 2/Kids[7 0 R 9 0 R]>>
> endobj
> 14 0 obj
> <</Type/Catalog/Pages 6 0 R>>
> endobj
> 15 0 obj
> <</Producer(iTextSharp’ 5.5.13.1 ©2000-2019 iText Group NV (AGPL-version))/CreationDate(D:20201021094517+03'00')/ModDate(D:20201021094517+03'00')>>
> endobj
> xref
> 0 16
> 0000000000 65535 f 
> 0000195708 00000 n 
> 0000225918 00000 n 
> 0000000015 00000 n 
> 0000040074 00000 n 
> 0000154680 00000 n 
> 0000227285 00000 n 
> 0000155771 00000 n 
> 0000155926 00000 n 
> 0000156928 00000 n 
> 0000157040 00000 n 
> 0000195526 00000 n 
> 0000197355 00000 n 
> 0000225727 00000 n 
> 0000227342 00000 n 
> 0000227388 00000 n 
> trailer
> <</Size 16/Root 14 0 R/Info 15 0 R/ID [ 
> ]>>
> %iText-5.5.13.1
> startxref
> 227554
> %%EOF

How can i get this pdf, and get text from it?

Comment: I used the body and created a pdf, and i got 2 blank pages when looking using Adobe PDF viewer.

Comment: When i used the body and created a pdf when i opened it i got 2 pages too but they were empty

Comment: Yes... that means there is no text content in that pdf or data is corupted

Comment: i don`t know why this happens. When i submit the form the pdf file is automatically downloaded, maybe there is a way to get the file from request?

Comment: May be... check the request and response using dev tools

Comment: but the file is downloaded, how can it be?

Comment: is this string only what i can get from request, or a can get exactly the file itself?